# Stata Loop for lagged variable

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, stata

i want to regress two variables **r** and **in**.
But i want to test multiple lags for the variable **in** and check which lag delivers the best fit for Rsquared.

I want to test -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3

```
regress r l.in 
regress r l2.in
regress r l3.in

 (.....)
```

Is it possible to do this using a loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
forval k = 1/7 { 
    regress r l`k'.in
}
```